# What is the relation between the sides of regular $n$- and $m$-gons inscribed inside a unit radius circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

Suppose a regular $m$-gon is inscribed inside a unit circle. And suppose a regular $n$-gon is inscribed in another unit circle. What's the relation between sides of $m$ and $n$?

I know $$l_{2n}=\sqrt{2R^2 - R\sqrt{4R^2-l_{n}^2}}$$

where $l_n$ is the side of a regular $n$-sided polygon inscribed in a circle with $R$ radius.

But how can I use this equation to derive a relation between $m$ and $n$?

Comment: The side of the $7$-gon is not expressible using square roots and so I don't expect a simple relationship between $l_7$ and $l_4$ say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the triangle of 2 consecutive vertices and the centerpoint of a regular $n$-gon, then it is clear that the centri-angle will be $\varphi_n=2\pi/n$. Thus the side length of a regular $n$-gon is being given by
$$s_n=2R\sin(\varphi_n/2)=2R\sin(\pi/n)$$
Therefrom you clearly get
$$\frac{s_n}{s_m}=\frac{\sin(\pi/n)}{\sin(\pi/m)}$$
--- rk